# get dsa signature value in octect string

Tags: c#

I am trying to read the octect string value of attribute dsa-signature. I got the field from default naming context properties. But its in byte array, when I try to convert it into a string it give wrong output.

Does anyone knows how to do correct octect converion?

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DC=cobra,DC=net");
            PropertyValueCollection propCol = entry.Properties["dSASignature"];
            Console.WriteLine(propCol.PropertyName + " : " + propCol.Value);
            System.Text.UTF8Encoding enc = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
            string str = enc.GetString((System.Byte[])propCol.Value);
            Console.WriteLine("value : " + str);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> But its in byte array, when I try to convert it into a string it give wrong output.

It's a byte array. Just an arbitrary sequence of bytes. It's *not* UTF-8-encoded text, which is what you're treating it as.

If you want to display the bytes formatted as hex, you can use:

```
byte[] data = (byte[]) propCol.Value;
string hex = BitConverter.ToString(data);
```

If you need to transfer it more efficiently but as text, you could use base64... but ideally you should treat it *as* a byte array for as long as possible, given that fundamentally it's just binary data.

Comment: thanks jon, but that i tried already and will not give correct output.

above will give below output which is nothing but just bytes only
01-00-00-00-28-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-96-3D-39-12-2E-0C-36-41-81-27-65-90-7A-FD-F4-B2

Comment: @sunder: Well what do you consider "correct output"? That's giving you the hex representation of the byte array. It's an accurate representation of the data you're fetching. What are you expecting and why?

Comment: yes that hex representation which is exactly machine with value in default naming context GUI. But the information which comes from this raw data is this

43242122-71ff-48e7-9296-1546887c14cc    2012-07-16 16:45:23
a guid id of domain controller, a date etc. Which I was trying to achieve.

Comment: @sunder: Then you need to find the format of the data. Do you have any documentation around that?

Comment: I tried finding this in msdn how can i convert back this into octet string but still no luck. I will continue doing same. So I quickly added this here hoping someone might had done this in past.

Comment: @sunder: I think you've misunderstood the meaning of the phrase "octet string" - that just means "sequence of bytes". So what you've got is *already* an octet string. If you want to impose some *meaning* on the octet string to convert it to a date/time, GUID etc, that's a different matter.

Comment: sorry @jon for my poor english, but I know I got octet string and its series or 8 bytes or 16 depends on OS. But I am looking in msdn how to get the meaningful information out of that octet string.